# About online distributed environment

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, distributed-computing

I am learning Mapreduce and Hadoop now. I know I can do some tests and run some samples on a singe node. But I really want to do some practice on a real distributed environment. So I want to ask :
Is there a website which can offer a distributed environment for me to do some experiments?

Somebody told me that I can use Amazon web service to build a distributed environment. Is it real? Does someone have such an experience?

And I want to know how you guys learn hadoop before you use it in your work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There are a few options:

- If you just want to learn about the Map/Reduce paradigm, I would recommend you take a look at [JSMapReduce](http://jsmapreduce.com/). This is embedded directly in the browser, you have nothing to install, and you can create real Map/Reduce programs.
- If you want to learn about Hadoop specifically, Amazon has this thing called [Elastic Map Reduce](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/) which is essentially Hadoop running on AWS, so this enables you to write your Hadoop job, decide how many machines you want in your cluster, which type of machines you want, and then run it, and EMR will do everything, bootstrap the machines for you, run your job and store the results on S3. I would recommend looking at [this tutorial](http://www.slideshare.net/DrSkippy27/amazon-elastic-map-reduce-getting-started-with-hadoop) to get an idea how to setup a job on EMR. Just remember, EMR is **not free**, so you'll have to pay for your computing resources.

Alternatively if you're not looking to pay the cost of EMR, you could always setup Hadoop on your local machine in non-distributed mode, and experiment with it, as described [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/single_node_setup.html). Even if it's a single node setup, the abstractions will be the same as if you were using a big cluster, so it's a good way to get up to speed and then go on EMR or a real cluster when you want to get serious.

Comment: Thanks very much, Charles! Your answers are just what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon offers a [free tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/), so you can spin up some vms and try experimenting that way.  The micro instances they have aren't very powerful, but are fine for small scale tests.

You can also spin up VMs on your desktop if it is powerful enough.  I have done this myself using [VMPlayer](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/).  You can install any flavor of Linux you like for free.  [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) is pretty easy to start with. When you setup the networking for your VMs, be sure to use bridged networking.  That way each VM will get its own IP address on your network so they can communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's maybe not about '100% online' but should give really good alternative with some details.

If you are not ready to pay for online cluster resources (such as EMR solution mentioned here) and you don't like to build your own cluster but you are not satisfied with single node setup, you can try to build virtual cluster on powerful enough desktop.

- You need minimun 3 VM, I prefer Ubuntu. 4 is better. To see real Hadoop you need minimal replication factor 3. So you need 3 dataNode, 3 taskTrackers. Well, you also need nameNode / JobTracker - it could be one of nodes used for dataNode but I'd recommend to have separate VM. If you need HBase, for example, you again need one Master and minimum 3 RegionServer. So, again, you need 3 but better 4 VM,
- There is pretty good free product, Cloudera CDH which is 'somewhat commercial' Hadoop distribution. They also have manager with GUI and simplified installation. BTW they have even prepared demo VMs but I never have used them. You can [download everything here](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Downloads). They also host lot of materials about Hadoop and their environment.

Alternative between completely free solution with VMs on desktop and paid service like EMR is your virtual cluster built on top of one dedicated server if you have spare. This is what I personally did. One physical server powered by VmWare free solution, 4 virtual machine, 1 SSD for OS and 3 'general' HDD for storages. Every VM runs Ubuntu 11.04 (again free). Cloudera manager free edition, CDH. So everything is free but you need some hardware that is often available as spare. And you have playground. OK, you need to invest time but by my mind you will get greatest experience from this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not know much about it, another option may be Greenplum's analytic workbench (1000 node cluster w/ Hadoop for testing): http://www.greenplum.com/solutions/analytics-workbench

Comment: Reading about it, it definitely seems like that cluster is not available for random people to try things on.  It's for validating scaled out hadoop features for enterprise deployments.